# ¿Cómo puedo editar las opciones de un menú con tkinter, python 3.7?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

Verán estoy haciendo mi interfaz en python 3.7 con ayuda de tkinter, y quiero hacerlo vertical, pero como se puede ver en la imagen, las opciones me salen hacia abajo y quiero que salgan hacia la derecha. ¿Es eso posible? Además me gustaría poder editar el tamaño de fuente de las opciones. ¿Existe una forma de hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import PhotoImage


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title ("Prototipo")

instrumento = tkinter.StringVar(window)
genero = tkinter.StringVar(window)
compas = tkinter.StringVar(window)
duracion = tkinter.StringVar(window)
velnegra = tkinter.StringVar(window)
instrumento.set("Instrumento Musical")
genero.set("Género Musical")
compas.set("Compás")
duracion.set("Duración")
velnegra.set("Velocidad Negra")


btn_elegirIns = tkinter.OptionMenu(window,instrumento,"Guitarra","Piano")
btn_elegirIns.config(font=("Century Gothic",10),height=2, width=20)
btn_elegirIns.place(x=40,y=100)
btn_generoMus = tkinter.OptionMenu(window,genero, "POP","R&B")
btn_generoMus.config(font=("Century Gothic",10),height=2, width=20)
btn_generoMus.place(x=40,y=150)
btn_elegirCompas = tkinter.OptionMenu(window,compas, "4/4","2/4")
btn_elegirCompas.config(font=("Century Gothic",10),height=2, width=20)
btn_elegirCompas.place(x=40,y=200)
btn_elegirDuracion = tkinter.OptionMenu(window,duracion, "30 segundos","60 segundos")
btn_elegirDuracion.config(font=("Century Gothic",10),height=2, width=20)
btn_elegirDuracion.place(x=40,y=250)
btn_elegirVelNe = tkinter.OptionMenu(window,velnegra, "72","100")
btn_elegirVelNe.config(font=("Century Gothic",10),height=2, width=20)
btn_elegirVelNe.place(x=40,y=300)

window.geometry('950x550') #Definir tamaño de la ventana.
window.resizable(0,0)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

La ubicación del submenú de un `OptionMenu`, no es configurable, (o al menos no he podido encontrar la forma), pero si puedes modificar el tamaño de la letra. Te sugiero, armar una clase propia para crear estos ítems y configurarlos de manera más simple:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import StringVar

class MyOptionMenu(tkinter.OptionMenu):

    def __init__(self, master, status, x, y, options, func=None):
        self.var = StringVar(master)
        self.var.set(status)
        self.command = self.func if func is None else func
        tkinter.OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, command=self.command, *options)
        self.config(font=('Century Gothic',(10)),bg='white', height=2, width=20)
        self['menu'].config(font=('Century Gothic',(10)),bg='white')
        self.place(x=x,y=y)

    def func(self,value):
        print(value)
```

Notas:

- Con `self['menu'].config(font=('Century Gothic',(10)),bg='white')` configuramos la letra del ítem
- `options` para indicar los ítems, pero habrá que hacerlo como lista
- `func` para definir una función a ejecutar cuando se hace click en el ítem

Y para crear los menus:

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title ("Prototipo")

btn_elegirIns = MyOptionMenu(window,"Instrumento Musical", 40, 100, ["Guitarra","Piano"])
btn_generoMus = MyOptionMenu(window,"Género Musical", 40, 150, ["POP","R&B"])
btn_elegirCompas = MyOptionMenu(window, "Compás", 40, 200, ["4/4","2/4"])
btn_elegirDuracion = MyOptionMenu(window,"Duración", 40, 250, ["30 segundos","60 segundos"])
btn_elegirDuracion = MyOptionMenu(window,"Velocidad Negra", 40, 300, ["72","100"])

window.geometry('950x550') #Definir tamaño de la ventana.
window.resizable(0,0)
window.mainloop()
```